# Intercepting Laravel Passport Routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

What I am trying to do is tracking which Passport Client is trying to communicate with the OAuth server. However I could not pinpoint any starting point on intercepting the current `oauth/authorize` route so that I could get the client info.

What I have tried to approach is trying to override/extend the current AuthorizationController defined by Passport however it doesn't replace it. I also tried looking into middlewares however I'm not sure where I could add a middleware and how I can get the client info from the middleware.